# Using Image map so a new image replaces the old image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm currently trying to use image map to replace an image. The first image gets replaced by the second image however I have no luck on getting the third image to replace the second one.

javascript:

```
    <script>
        dcoument.getElementById("img1").src="MSWORD.jpg";
        document.getElementById("img2").src="ClickFile.png";
        documnet.getElementById("img3").src="NewFile.png"

        function replaceImage(imgid, source, mapid)
        {
          var image = document.getElementById(imgid);
          image.src= source;
          var newmap = document.getElementById(mapid);
          var origin = document.getElementById("ClickFile");
          origin.innerHTML = newmap.innerHTML;
        }
    </script>
```

Html5

```
                <img id="img1" src="MSWORD.jpg" alt="Microsoft Word"
                style="width:fill-available;height:fill-available" usemap="#ClickFile"> 

                 <map name="ClickFile">

                 <area href="javascript:(function(){
                    document.getElementById('img1').src='ClickFile.png';})()"
                    shape="rect" coords="58,50,0,25">
                 </map>    

                 <map name="image1" id="image1">
                    <area href="javascript:replaceImage('img1', 'ClickFile.png', 'img2')"
                      shape="rect" coords="50,58,0,25">
                </map>

                <area href="javascript:(function(){
                    document.getElementById('img2').src='NewFile.png';})()"
                    shape="rect" coords="122,103,0,141">

                <map name="image2" id="image2">
                    <area href="javascript:replaceImage('img2', 'Newfile.png', 'img3')"
                    shape="rect" coords="122,103,0,141">   
                </map>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Or event better a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but make sure your `</map>` tag comes immediately after the`<area …>` tags within it. Right now your second and third maps are inside the first map which is probably confusing the browser.

Comment: I've corrected this however still facing the same problem